# Array is filled with 'null' - LibGDX

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, rgb, bufferedimage

In my LibGDX game, I am trying to work out a way to create a map based on the pixels in a .PNG image file. I am using the BufferedImage class to convert and store the RGB values from the image into an Array, which then returns a Tile based on its value. However, the Array that contains all of the Tiles is just filled with '`null`' values.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.survivegameandroidtest.survive.player.Player;
import com.survivegameandroidtest.survive.tiles.ConcreteTile;
import com.survivegameandroidtest.survive.tiles.GrassTile;

public class Level {

Tile[] tiles;
int[] levelPixels;
AssetManager manager;
Player player;
SpriteBatch batch;

public Level(String path) {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Level.class.getResource(path));
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        tiles = new Tile[width * height];
        levelPixels = new int[width * height];
        image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, levelPixels, 0, width);
        } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Level could not load");
    }
}


//GRASS = 0x24ff00
//CONCRETE = 0x8b8b8b
public void generateLevel() {
    for(int i = 0; i < levelPixels.length; i++) {
        if(levelPixels[i] == 0x24ff) tiles[i] = new GrassTile(manager.get("grass.png", Texture.class), new Vector2(i * 10, i * 10), new Vector2(10,10));
        if(levelPixels[i] == 0x8b8b8b) tiles[i] = new ConcreteTile(manager.get("concrete.png", Texture.class), new Vector2(i * 10, i * 10), new Vector2(10,10));
    }
}

public void update() {

}

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {

}

}
```

If I add a `System.out.println(tiles[1])` - this will print 'null' in the console.

This code below is in a separate class, where I call the generate method and store the tiles Array in an Iterator. In the draw method, an if-statement is used to determine whether the current Tile in the Iterator is null, if it is, then it doesn't draw/render the tile. On the game, there is only a white screen with my player, indicating that all of the values in the `tiles[]` Array are equal to 'null'. If the if-statement was to be removed, I would get a `NullPointerException`.

**SHOW METHOD**

```
level = new Level("/level.png");
tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();

for(int i = 0; i < level.tiles.length; i++) {
    level.generateLevel();
    tiles.add(level.tiles[i]);
}
```

**RENDER METHOD**

```
tileIterator = tiles.iterator();

while(tileIterator.hasNext()) {
    final Tile cur = tileIterator.next();
    if(cur != null) {
        cur.update();
        cur.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

If I add:

```
if (levelPixels[i] != 0x24ff || levelPixels[i] != 0x8b8b8b) {
    tiles[i] = new GrassTile(manager.get("grass.png", Texture.class),
        new Vector2(i * 10, i * 10),
        new Vector2(10, 10));
}
```

Then I receive a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the `levelPixels` array. It should be filled at the `image.getRGB()` method, so you should start with checking if values of this array are not equal to `0` after calling this method. Anyway, it's obvious that none of the values of this array is equal to `0x24ff` or `0x8b8b8b`, that is why `Level.tiles` array remains just array of `nulls`

Can you please try the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < levelPixels.length; i++)
{
    if (levelPixels[i] == 0x24ff) {
        tiles[i] = new GrassTile(manager.get("grass.png", Texture.class),
                new Vector2(i * 10, i * 10),
                new Vector2(10, 10));
    } else if (levelPixels[i] == 0x8b8b8b) {
        tiles[i] = new ConcreteTile(manager.get("concrete.png", Texture.class),
                new Vector2(i * 10, i * 10),
                new Vector2(10, 10));
    } else {
        tiles[i] = new GrassTile(manager.get("grass.png", Texture.class),
                new Vector2(i * 10, i * 10),
                new Vector2(10, 10));
    }
}
```

And also please init `manager`: `AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();`

Comment: How could I get all of the RGB values stored in this Array instead of just zeros? Thanks btw

Comment: But doesn't image.getRGB return RGB values like `0x24ff` and `0x8b8b8b`? Do I have to replace them with another number in the if-statement?

Comment: @user3461933 values depend on the picture. You should check values inside `levelPixels` array by using debugger

Comment: Using this, I get a `NullPointerException` on the line:

            tiles[i] = new GrassTile(manager.get("grass.png", Texture.class),
                new Vector2(i * 10, i * 10),
                new Vector2(10, 10));

Comment: @user3461933 I think I got the reason: `manager` is `null`. You declare this field, but don't init it.

Comment: Ahhhhh. Sorry for being  complete waste of your time. :S
Thanks for all the help though!

Answer (score 1):

your tiles are conditionally populated(which means there is a chance of them not getting populated)

```
public void generateLevel() {
    for(int i = 0; i < levelPixels.length; i++) {
        if(levelPixels[i] == 0x24ff) tiles[i] = new GrassTile(manager.get("grass.png", Texture.class), new Vector2(i * 10, i * 10), new Vector2(10,10));
        if(levelPixels[i] == 0x8b8b8b) tiles[i] = new ConcreteTile(manager.get("concrete.png", Texture.class), new Vector2(i * 10, i * 10), new Vector2(10,10));
    }
}
```